# blast nt vs Genbank

Tags: blast, blastn

What is the difference between these two databases?

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/
 and
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genbank/

I understand that BLAST database has both nt for nucleotide and np for protein. But genbank is also for genomic database. So what is the difference between nt and Genbank databases?

Thanks

Comment: They are the same data, but the interegation of the database is very different. Blast uses a similarity algorithm but Genbank uses record referencing. It is better to limit the quesiton towards a specific biological problem for a more detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the BLAST folder contains pre-formatted databases for BLAST whereas the GenBank folder contains sequences.